# Cannot generate a pyinstaller binary from python files or from cython generated library files

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, cython, pyinstaller

I wish to make a standalone executable binary from a small python (2.7) project on linux.

**My project is structured this way:**

```
- proto/
    - main.py
    - file1.py
    - file2.py
    - gui/
        - __init__.py
        - file3.py
        - file4.py
        - qt/
            - __init__.py
            - file5.py
            - file6.py
    - external/
        - __init__.py
        - ext1/
            - __init__.py
            - file7.py
            - file8.py
```

**1- I converted all .py files to .so files** (except `main.py` and all `__init__.py`) in a separate folder, using cython/distutil :

```
-proto_cython/
    - main.py
    - file1.so
    - file2.so
    - gui/
        - __init__.py
        - file3.so
        - file4.so
        - qt/
            - __init__.py
            - file5.so
            - file6.so
    - external/
        - __init__.py
        - ext1/
            - __init__.py
            - file7.so
            - file8.so
```

And it works fine when I run `python main.py`

**2 - Now I want to get rid of .py files completely**, so I try to do it using pyinstaller. It may not be the right tool by the way.

`pyinstaller --onefile --clean --name=gui main.py`

**2.a - pyinstaller from folder proto_cython**

I get this error when I run dist/gui:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 416, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
  File "mainwindow.py", line 9, in init gui.mainwindow (/home/cyrille/proto/gui/mainwindow.c:2312)
ImportError: No module named qt.ui_mainwindow
```

(There is a `ui_mainwindow.so` file in `gui/qt`)

Well, before trying to correct it, let's try without cython/distutil generated .so files (only original .py files)

**2.b - pyinstaller from folder proto**

I get this error when I run dist/gui:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 271, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/cyrille/proto/build/gui/out00-PYZ.pyz/gui.mainwindow", line 16, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 271, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/cyrille/proto/build/gui/out00-PYZ.pyz/gui.viewerconfigwidget", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 271, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/cyrille/proto/build/gui/out00-PYZ.pyz/viewer", line 15, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 271, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/cyrille/proto/build/gui/out00-PYZ.pyz/sklearn.decomposition", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 271, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/cyrille/proto/build/gui/out00-PYZ.pyz/sklearn.decomposition.nmf", line 22, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 271, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/cyrille/proto/build/gui/out00-PYZ.pyz/sklearn.utils", line 17, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 271, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/cyrille/proto/build/gui/out00-PYZ.pyz/sklearn.utils.sparsetools", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 416, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
  File "_min_spanning_tree.pyx", line 8, in init sklearn.utils.mst._min_spanning_tree (sklearn/utils/sparsetools/_min_spanning_tree.c:4754)
ImportError: No module named _graph_validation
```

**3 - So, it looks I have more than one problem here**:

- pyinstaller doesn't seem to like [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) module
- pyinstaller can't find imports from cython generated files

Any idea to go further ?

**EDIT**
In both cases (pure python and .so files), the generated gui.spec looks like:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['proto.py'],
             pathex=['/home/cyrille/proto'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None,
             excludes=None,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='proto_gui',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True
```

Comment: where your `objective C`? Read this: http://sadopy.blogspot.com.tr/2015/09/py-installer-wxpython-error-corecore-etc.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your are suggesting. I don't have any objective C in my code at the moment. In doubt, I installed gobjc and gnustep-devel, but that changed nothing.

Comment: test your `lsbcc` and `python ./waf configure build install` output ?

Comment: The webpage you linked is kind of hard to read. Google english (or french) translation is almost unreadable, at least for me. If I understand correctly, you want me to transform python source code to objective C source code ? Right now, I already have (ansi) C files, generated by cython from my python files. I intend to gradually go from pure python to cython in a near future, so, I don't think objective C will help me here.

Comment: the solution is successful, then the answer is in the wrong section of the change.